# How do I resolve this sudo command error?

Tags: macos, sudo

When I run sudo commands on my Mac I get the following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. enter code herePlease visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

I have installed the latest JDK but still it shows me the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Does this happen for *any* `sudo` command (e.g. `sudo echo test`), or only when you try to run something in java?

Comment: Other commands such as 'sudo echo test' work. I wantd to run sudo apt get as I wanted to update all my libraries but then it shows me that error.

Comment: Are you trying to use the [Advanced Package Tool (`apt`)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt), which many Linux distros use for package management? macOS doesn't use that, and doesn't handle updates the same way (although there are systems like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) that use somewhat similar systems to install and update add-on software). On macOS, the `apt` command invokes the Java [Annotation Processing Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html), which is completely unrelated.

Comment: Oh okay! so how do I update the packages like python and the remaining stuff? Like do I need to use homebrew or is there any other work around?

Comment: In general, the software that comes with the OS gets updated (or not) with system updates. For things that aren't supplied with the OS or where the OS-supplied version is old (like python), it depends on the particular program. For example, there are separate [python installers for macOS](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/). If you have more questions, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a much better place to ask about things like this.